Stop a function being too 'wild' - example if i enter K5 it comes up with all K5 plus K51, K52 etc
The formula is:
=IFERROR(INDEX(AllData,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($K$3,AnalCode))*ISNUMBER(SEARCH($K$4,ProjectCode)),ROW(AllData)-MIN(ROW(AllData))+1),ROW(H1)),COLUMN(H1)),"")
$K$3 is an analysis code and $K$4 is a Project Code.
Analysis codes are {SA, SR, SW, etc.}
Project codes are {E1, E5, E50, E51, etc.}
If I enter E on its own, I get all 'E', happy with that. However, if I enter E5 I get E5, E50 and E51 etc.. I really want only E5 if I enter E5. Sometimes I may want all E5*. Is it possible to use the star as a wildcard somewhere? Ie: if I enter E5 I only get E5 but if I enter E5* I get all E5, E50 and E51 etc.
Thanks

If you need only E5 then dont use SEARCH() function then simply use "E5"=ProjectCode range. also wildcard is not needed when using the SEARCH() function. Also in your post title it says K5 where as post body says E5 is it different or a typo here. also you can stop the function by using the kth value as 1, still its not clear since there is no ample amount of some mock data with the expected output

Hard to tell without sharing data. Maybe use SEARCH($K$4&IF(1-ISERR(FIND("*",$K$4)),,""," "),ProjectCode&" ") (untested)

How do I add a small set of data to my question? Can't find the answer in 'Help'.

https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables

Assuming you're trying to do row-column lookup with or without wildcards.
If you have Microsoft 365 (for using LAMBDA, FILTER etc.), could you try something like this using FILTER instead of INDEX:

Filter column(s) based on selection (data_matching_analysis_code)
Then filter the rows matching the project code.

COUNTIF is helpful as you can do a wildcard match when needed (exact match when wildcard is not used.)




A
B
C
D
E




1
Analysis/Project Codes
SA
SR
RW
SW


2
E1
9
5
7
34


3
E5
4
10
3
33


4
E50
6
1
10
43


5
E51
7
1
9
54


6







7
Select Analysis Code
S*





8
Select Project Code
E5*









Defined name
Referes to




AnalysisData
=Sheet1!$B$2:$E$5


AnalysisCode
=Sheet1!$B$1:$E$1


ProjectCode
=Sheet1!$A$2:$A$5


is_matching
=LAMBDA(lookup_value,lookup_array,MAP(lookup_array,LAMBDA(val,COUNTIF(val,lookup_value))))


data_matching_analysis_code
=FILTER(AnalysisData,is_matching(Sheet1!$B$7,AnalysisCode))






=FILTER(data_matching_analysis_code, is_matching($B$8,ProjectCode))






4
10
33


6
1
43


7
1
54



